# Salesforce query error

Tags: soql, contracts

What is wrong with my SOQL query?

```
SELECT ContractNumber, AccountId, Id, OwnerId, RecordTypeId, Contract_Level__c, Parent_Contract_Number__c, StartDate, EndDate, Status,
FROM Contract 
WHERE AccountID != null
```

Comment: When asking for help about errors, it's always a good idea to include the exact error message that you're getting (i.e. don't paraphrase/shorten it, because you'll leave out important information if you try)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an extra comma (,) after `Status` and before `FROM`

Your query should be:

```
SELECT ContractNumber, AccountId, Id, OwnerId, RecordTypeId, Contract_Level__c, Parent_Contract_Number__c, StartDate, EndDate, Status
FROM Contract 
WHERE AccountID != null
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a comma after the last field in your SELECT clause
`Status, FROM Contract`

That needs to be removed, as we cannot have a comma between the last field name and the `FROM` keyword